# SQL Server 2012 Express Command Line install

Tags: sql, command-line, installation, sql-server-2012-express

I am trying to install SQL Server 2012 Express SP1 via the command line, however it just quietly fails, no error messages. Can anyone help?

Here are the commands I'm using.

```
c:\>sqlexpr32_x86_enu.exe /QS /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS 
         /ACTION=Install /ROLE=AllFeatures_WithDefaults /ENU 
         /UpdateEnabled=1 /UpdateSource=MU 
         /FEATURES=SQLENGINE,REPLICATION 
         /INSTALLSHAREDDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server" 
         /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /INSTANCEID=SQLEXPRESS 
         /INSTANCEDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server" 
         /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" 
         /AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic 
         /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /ENABLERANU 
         /SQLCOLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" 
         /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS" 
         /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD="P@ssword1" 
         /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN /TCPENABLED=1 /NPENABLED=1
```

Comment: did you run the comand from an elevated command prompt?

Comment: Yes, I ran as administrator

Comment: I suggest you to remove the `/QS ` flag since it hides any error message... ;)